# Font Awesome 5.0.13 some icons are not working

Tags: css, font-awesome-5

I am using Font Awesome 5.0.13. Some icons are not showing in Chrome. For example "fa-instagram". Is there a way to fix it or just wait for the next release? Here is what I see in chrome.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-3AB7yXWz4OeoZcPbieVW64vVXEwADiYyAEhwilzWsLw+9FgqpyjjStpPnpBO8o8S" crossorigin="anonymous">
<a href="#" target="_blank" class="icon-facebook">
  <i class="fab fa-facebook-f">
    </i>
</a>
<a href="#" target="_blank" class="icon-twitter">
  <i class="fab fa-twitter">
    </i>
</a>
<a href="#" target="_blank" class="icon-google_plus">
  <i class="fab fa-google-plus-g">
    </i>
</a>
<a href="#" target="_blank" class="icon-pinterest">
  <i class="fab fa-pinterest">
    </i>
</a>
<a href="#" target="_blank" class="icon-linkedin">
  <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in">
    </i>
</a>
<a href="#" target="_blank" class="icon-instagram">
  <i class="fab fa-instagram">
    </i>
</a>
<a href="#" target="_blank" class="icon-tumblr">
  <i class="fab fa-tumblr">
    </i>
</a>
```

Comment: The integrity attribute is incorrect. Where did you get the value from? Removed it and it works

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to remove the integrity, just like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css">

<a href="#" target="_blank" class="icon-facebook">
  <i class="fab fa-facebook-f">
    </i>
</a>
<a href="#" target="_blank" class="icon-twitter">
  <i class="fab fa-twitter">
    </i>
</a>
<a href="#" target="_blank" class="icon-google_plus">
  <i class="fab fa-google-plus-g">
    </i>
</a>
<a href="#" target="_blank" class="icon-pinterest">
  <i class="fab fa-pinterest">
    </i>
</a>
<a href="#" target="_blank" class="icon-linkedin">
  <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in">
    </i>
</a>
<a href="#" target="_blank" class="icon-instagram">
  <i class="fab fa-instagram">
    </i>
</a>
<a href="#" target="_blank" class="icon-tumblr">
  <i class="fab fa-tumblr">
    </i>
</a>
```

Comment: Great! Thank @Jonjie

Answer (score 0):

The correct `<link>` with the hash is:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oi8o31xSQq8S0RpBcb4FaLB8LJi9AT8oIdmS1QldR8Ui7KUQjNAnDlJjp55Ba8FG" crossorigin="anonymous">`